# Make image relative (change position between computer and phone)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a site and I have a problem. When I try to upload an image, if I press f12 and use a phone view, it works perfectly. However, when I exit from the phone view and look on a full size PC, the position of the image changes.

This is the CSS for the image:

```css
#showpic {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 12%;
    height: 38vh;
}
```

and this is the image html

```
<div><img id="showpic" src="image/frontpic.jpg" /></div>
```

Full HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portLand.css" />
    </head>

        <body>
            <header id="header">
                <img src="image/headerlogo.png" id="LogoP"  alt="headerlogo" />
                <nav id="nav">
                    <a href="site.html"> <button class="btnMenu" style='width:17%'><b>Home</b></button> </a>
                    <a href="site.html"> <button class="btnMenu" style='width:17%'><b>America</b></button> </a>
                    <a href="site.html"> <button class="btnMenu" style='width:17%'><b>Europe</b></button> </a>
                    <a href="site.html"> <button class="btnMenu" style='width:17%'><b>About</b></button> </a>
                    <a href="site.html"> <button class="btnMenu" style='width:17%'><b>Contacts</b></button> </a>
                <nav>
            </header>
            <div><img id="showpic" src="image/frontpic.jpg" /></div>

        </body>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Full CSS

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #E6EEFC;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7vh;
    position: fixed;
    background: #0059FF;
}
#LogoP {
    top: 0;
    left: 7%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 7vh;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
    width: 80%;
    height: 5vh;
    margin-left: 21%;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
}
.btnMenu {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 2%;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
    font-size: 1.4vh;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, purple, white);
}
#showpic {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 12%;
    height: 38vh;
}
```

Comment: CSS media queries? check: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is ["responsive"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)